# Configuring SOAP for Tomcat - request always refused (403)

Tags: java, tomcat, soap, soapui

I have SOAP web service that is properly configure on weblogic server, but I am trying to make it work on Tomcat.

in my tomcat-users.xml I have user configured like this

```
<tomcat-users version="1.0" xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd">

 <role rolename="esknusers"/>
 <user password="password" roles="esknusers" username="esknuser"/>

</tomcat-users>
```

And in my web.xml the webservice is configured like this

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>SecurityConstraint_ESKN</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>ESKNWS</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/ESKN_WS</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>esknusers</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
    <security-role>
    <role-name>esknusers</role-name>
</security-role>
```

When I try to call this webservice through SOAP-UI it always returns 403. Any idea what could be the problem?

In Soap-ui I am using Basic Authentication through name and password

Message from SOAP-UI:

```
Access to the requested resource has been denied - The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it
```

Answer (score 1):

You've set up the role name, but you'll also need something the following in your `web.xml` file to tell Tomcat you're using BASIC authentication:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Basic Authentication</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

This should read usernames and passwords from your `conf/tomcat-users.xml` file by default.